# No definition for 'Name' found

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, methods

I have a class defined in a namespace:

```
namespace Artworking
{
    public class Category
    {
        int ID {get;set;}
        string Name {get;set;}

        public Category(int ID, string Name)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.Name = Name;
        }
        public Category(int ID)
        {
            using (CrystalCommon.MainContext db = new CrystalCommon.MainContext())
            {
                var q = (from c in db.tblArtworkTemplateCategories where c.ID == ID select c).SingleOrDefault();
                this.ID = q.ID;
                this.Name = q.CatName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my content page I fetch all the Categories from another function and add them a listbox control:

```
        // Category select
        Artworking.Category[] Cats = Artworking.CommonFunctions.FetchAllCategories(Master.LoggedInUser.Client.ID);
        foreach(Artworking.Category C in Cats){
            ListItem NewItem = new ListItem();
            NewItem.Text = C.Name;
            NewItem.Value = C.ID;
            CategorySelect.Items.Add(NewItem);
        }
```

However for some reason on the `NewItem.Text = C.Name` line it throws:

> CS1061: 'Artworking.Category' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Name' and no
>   extension method 'Name' accepting a
>   first argument of type

I'm a bit confused about this one, I thought it's all defined properly?

> 'Artworking.Category' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still need to add `public` before your property declarations inside the `Category` class.

Answer (score 4):

Your property `Name` should be marked `public` (as should `ID` based on the fact you're trying to access it outside of the class.)

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get;set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }

    ....
}
```

One other minor suggestion - why not reference the `Artworking` namespace in your code through a `using` statement? It will make your code a little tidier, rather than having to continually type the complete namespace in multiple lines:

```
using Artworking;

// Category select
Category[] Cats = CommonFunctions.FetchAllCategories(Master.LoggedInUser.Client.ID);

foreach(Category C in Cats)
{
    ....
}
```